# How a NSWindow knows it is visible?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

Is there a `ViewDidAppear` equivalent method for a `NSWindow` on cocoa?

What method runs the moment a window is visible?

I know `awakeFromNib` is triggered but the window is not visible when it fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `windowWillLoad` and `windowDidLoad` to perform tasks before the window nib file is loaded or to perform tasks after the window nib file is loaded.
See [NSWindowController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you subclass `NSWindowController`, you can intercept `showWindow:` messages.

[image]

Comment: where is the NSWindowController when you create a blank project? Sorry about the question, but I am very new to cocoa.

Comment: You do not see it on a blank project (you have to use the app delegate). But when adding NIB with windows, you will have to create the WindowController. Which window are you trying to access? The one you get in a dialog-ased application, or one you have added to your project ?

Comment: In the app delegate, you have : `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification;`, `…WillHide`, `…DidHide`, `…DidBecomeActive`, etc...

Comment: The main window created for the project. I have created a custom class for it and assigned.

Comment: Then, put your code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. It is generated for you.What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I see now. I will hook that to the delegate. Thanks!